# Calculate the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(2\sqrt{2}-3)^j$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would appreciate if anyone could help with the summation

\begin{equation*}
\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(2\sqrt{2}-3)^j.
\end{equation*}

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: Geometric series and $|2\sqrt 2-3|<1$

Comment: So it equals to (2sqrt(2)-3)/(1-(2sqrt(2)-3))?

Comment: @JieLi Yep exactly!

Comment: Following up on the hint and multiplying by the conjugate of the radical we get $\frac{(2\sqrt{2}-3)(2+\sqrt{2})}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=a}^{\infty} r^n=\frac{r^a}{1-r} \\when |r|<1$$

So $2\sqrt{2}-3<1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2\sqrt{2}-3)^n=\frac{(2\sqrt{2}-3)^1}{1-(2\sqrt{2}-3)}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}-3}{1-2\sqrt{2}+3}=\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{2}-2)$$